# Prestashop 1.6 encrypt password can't reproduce the encryption in nodejs

Tags: php, prestashop, md5, prestashop-1.6

I try to reproduce the hash of prestashop's password with nodejs and I find a difference in php.

```
<?php 
define(_COOKIE_KEY_, 'foo');
$pass = 'bar';

$hash1 = md5(_COOKIE_KEY_ . $pass);
$hash2 = md5('foo' . $pass);

// $hash1 !== $hash2
```

In NodeJS (with md5 module) I found only the $hash2 but impossible to find $hash1.

Someone know why ? and how to reproduce ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: @Lithilion I know md5 is unsafe but prestashop is like that, so until update in 1.7 i can't do anything